# Python figure crashing and is unresponsive

Tags: python, debugging, figure

I'm trying to make a script where it'll go to each point and save a figure of the plot if the point is good or not. But the figure is just unresponsive/blank. Any ideas?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = range(-3, 3, 1)

for moving in range(len(A)):
    parsedFile = 'TEST/data_%d' % (moving)

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(A)
    plt.plot(A[moving],"rx")

plt.show(block=False)
plotChoice = raw_input("Is this a good value? (y/n): ")

if plotChoice == 'y':
    plt.savefig(parsedFile + '.jpg', pdi=1000)
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()
else:
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()
```

Ran using PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

In non-interactive mode [plt.show()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) will block until the figure is closed. The `block` argument is experimental according to the documentation, and it seems to me that it won't work in your case. Well, at least it doesn't work for me.

To interact with the user of the plot you can use a [Button](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Button) widget. Two buttons 'Yes' and 'No' can be placed directly to the plot. Here you can find an example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/buttons.html

Button placement is not straightforward, so to simplifiy things a little bit I used plot title for the question and added buttons alongside. May seem ugly, feel free to adjust to your needs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

ax = plt.subplot()
plt.title('Is this a good value?')

A = range(-3, 3, 1)

for moving in range(len(A)):
    parsedFile = 'TEST/data_%d' % moving

    ax.plot(A)
    ax.plot(A[moving], 'rx')

def yes(event):
    plt.savefig(parsedFile + '.jpg', pdi=1000)
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()

def no(event):
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()

yes_axes = plt.axes([0.69, 0.91, 0.1, 0.075])
yes_button = Button(yes_axes, 'Yes')
yes_button.on_clicked(yes)

no_axes = plt.axes([0.80, 0.91, 0.1, 0.075])
no_button = Button(no_axes, 'No')
no_button.on_clicked(no)

plt.show()
```